# WSO2 Data Services Server error calling stored procedure

Tags: jdbc, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, mssql-jdbc

I have been able to successfully call a Microsoft SQL Server stored procedure from WSO2 Data Services Server (DSS) and return results.  However, getting result sets back from certain stored procedures results in a com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This operation is not supported.  After some experimentation, I found at least one criteria that results in this error.  That is when I create a temp table within the stored procedure.  My guess is that this is resulting in a type of result that the DSS code is not expecting or not handling correctly.

The Microsoft SQL Server driver jar file I am using is from sqljdbc4.jar that is part of the August 2015 release of Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.2 for SQL Server.  The SQL Server version is SQL Server 2012 (11.0.5582.0).

The example stored procedure I created to reproduce this case is as follows:

```
CREATE Proc [dbo].[example_proc]
(
    @id       varchar(255)
)
AS

BEGIN
Create table #temp
(
         command_name       varchar(50), 
         transactions     int,
         timeouts           int, 
         errors             int
)

insert into #temp values ('abc', 5, 10, 25)

select command_name, transactions, timeouts, errors from #temp

drop table #temp 

/*
    select 'test' "command_name", 5 "transactions", 10 "timeouts", 25 "errors"
    */
END
```

The sample configuration for the data service is as follows:

```
<data disableStreaming="true" name="MESCDataService" transports="http https">
   <config enableOData="false" id="MESCDataSource">
       <property name="carbon_datasource_name">MESCDataSource</property>
   </config>
   <query id="test" useConfig="MESCDataSource">
      <sql>{ call dbo.example_proc (?) }</sql>
      <result element="Results" rowName="Result">
         <element column="test_column" name="TestColumn" xsdType="string"/>
      </result>
      <param name="val" sqlType="STRING"/>
   </query>
   <operation disableStreaming="true" name="test">
      <call-query href="test">
         <with-param name="val" query-param="val"/>
      </call-query>
   </operation>
</data>
```

The configuration for the Carbon Data Source is:

Driver: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
URL format: jdbc:sqlserver://[hostname]:[port];databaseName=[dbname];

Here is the excerpt from the wso2carbon.log file with more details on the error:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-04-21 09:01:00,016] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBInOutMessageReceiver} -  Error in in-out message receiver {org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBInOutMessageReceiver}
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Nested Exception:-
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processStoredProcQuery': This operation is not supported.
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: MESCDataService
Location: \MESCDataService.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: test
Current Params: {Id=3}
Nested Exception:-
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This operation is not supported.


    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.dispatch.SingleDataServiceRequest.processRequest(SingleDataServiceRequest.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.dispatch.DataServiceRequest.dispatch(DataServiceRequest.java:344)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DataServiceProcessor.dispatch(DataServiceProcessor.java:41)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(DBInOutMessageReceiver.java:52)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.java:42)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:173)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:231)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CSRFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CSRFPreventionFilter.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CRLFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CRLFPreventionFilter.java:59)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processStoredProcQuery': This operation is not supported.
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: MESCDataService
Location: \MESCDataService.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: test
Current Params: {Id=3}
Nested Exception:-
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This operation is not supported.

    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.execute(DSOMDataSource.java:102)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.dispatch.SingleDataServiceRequest.processRequest(SingleDataServiceRequest.java:73)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processStoredProcQuery': This operation is not supported.
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: MESCDataService
Location: \MESCDataService.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: test
Current Params: {Id=3}
Nested Exception:-
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This operation is not supported.

    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.SQLQuery.processPreStoredProcQuery(SQLQuery.java:916)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.SQLQuery.runPreQuery(SQLQuery.java:2134)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.Query.execute(Query.java:285)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.CallQuery.executeElement(CallQuery.java:286)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.OutputElement.execute(OutputElement.java:89)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.operation.Operation.execute(Operation.java:61)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DataService.invoke(DataService.java:583)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.execute(DSOMDataSource.java:96)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This operation is not supported.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.NotImplemented(SQLServerStatement.java:565)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getMoreResults(SQLServerStatement.java:2061)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.SQLQuery.getFirstRSOfStoredProc(SQLQuery.java:1034)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.SQLQuery.processPreStoredProcQuery(SQLQuery.java:909)
    ... 61 more
```

Comment: is this stored procedure giving expected results when executed directly through mssql client?

Comment: Yes, it works when executing from SQL Server Management Studio.  I see no difference in that procedure if I use the temp table or not using that client.